# How to restore deleted files from zip archive?

Tags: archive, undelete

2-3 days ago I was extracting files from zip archive and deleting already extracted folder. But for some reason archive manager deleted not yet extracted folders even though I hadn't selected them. Are they long gone or is it possible to recover them somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)